# Recommended method for combining sources of randomness?

Tags: random, cryptography, multiplatform

In a recent article about potential compromised random number generators, I learnt that `/dev/random` combines multiple sources of randomness:

> "Torvalds argued in his mild outburst that the values from RdRand are combined with other sources of randomness, which would thwart any attempts to game the processor's output - but it's claimed that mix is trivial (involving just an exclusive OR) and can be circumvented by g-men." - [Torvalds shoots down call to yank 'backdoored' Intel RdRand in Linux crypto](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/09/10/torvalds_on_rrrand_nsa_gchq/)

This quote suggests that XORing these sources is too simple for cryptographic purposes. My question therefore is what method is recommended for combining multiple sources of randomness?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/42164/29927

Comment: @user814064 It's certainly related, but they're very different questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: @owlstead If that's the consensus, I'd be happy for it to be migrated.

Comment: @TomWright Flagged it, I cannot migrate myself (needs moderator attention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fortuna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_%28PRNG%29) is a CSPRNG designed to work with multiple pools of input. It samples from the various inputs, mixes them internally, and then produces an output stream. It  It's a good method for combining multiple entropy sources.

On the topic of current events, Linux's approach isn't necessarily wrong. XORing two PRNG streams isn't a bad technique. There haven't been any good arguments as to why the existing approach is unsafe, just wild speculation.

Comment: Obviously, using a secure PRNG on top of RdRand could take away serious speed advantages that RdRand provides. I presume that is why XOR is used...

Comment: @owlstead `/dev/random` has no speed to speak of. And for `/dev/urandom` you still need to produce the output using the CSPRNG into which you xor RdRand, so I don't see how xor-into-output provides any speed advantage over mix-into-pool.